# Multiple Kotlin MPP native libraries with common linked dependencies

Tags: gradle, kotlin, dynamic-linking, ios-frameworks, kotlin-multiplatform

I have multiple Kotlin MPP projects that I want to compile and use as separate libraries in iOS and Android. The MPP projects have their own build.gradle files and are combined into a composite build structure, so one task builds them all. This works well for building the jars. The iOS frameworks are also built but not the way I'd like.

There is a dependency structure among the libraries, for example a core library that all of the others use and another one that references all the others, and some in-between. When compiling the libraries, they come out as fat frameworks containing all of their dependencies. Their types are named with a prefix [according to their Kotlin project name](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html#name-translation) which makes types from different libraries incompatible in the consuming app, even though the types are the same in Kotlin.

Here is an example: let's say we have App, Lib_A and Lib_B. In Kotlin common_main, Lib_A references lib_b.Clazz of Lib_B. In Android, the same lib_b.Clazz can be referenced both from Lib_B and the App and between Lib_A and Lib_B. However, in iOS, since namespaces do not exist, Clazz is called Lib_ALib_BClazz in Lib_A and LibBClazz in Lib_B. To the App, these are therefore different types and cannot be used together. Also, in the compiled iOS frameworks, all visible transitative dependencies are included in each framework.

**Question**: Is there some way in Gradle to tell the MPP plugin not to include all the dependencies in each compiled iOS framework, so I can provide them all from App instead and their types will be compatible?

Here is the basic build.gradle for each Kotlin MPP project, that is then included in the composite build:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.61'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependencies" }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

kotlin {
    iosArm64 { 
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = project.name
        }
    }
    iosX64 { 
        binaries.framework {
            baseName = project.name
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.2'
                implementation 'Lib_B' // example
                implementation 'Lib_C' // example
            }
        }
        iosArm64Main {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.2'
            }
        }
        iosX64Main {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.2'
            }
        }
    }
}

task runBuildIosArm64(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'ProjectName/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['linkReleaseFrameworkIos']
    startParameter.setProjectProperties([
            'IOS_TARGET': 'iosArm64',
            'XCODE_CONFIGURATION': 'RELEASE'
    ])
}

task runBuildIosX64(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'ProjectName/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['linkReleaseFrameworkIos']
    startParameter.setProjectProperties([
            'IOS_TARGET': 'iosX64',
            'XCODE_CONFIGURATION': 'RELEASE'
    ])
}

task cleanFrameworksFolder(type: Delete) {
    delete 'ProjectName/build/xcode-frameworks'
}

task combineIosArchitectures(type: Exec) {
    executable 'lipo'
    args = [
            '-create',
            '-arch',  'arm64', 'ProjectName/build/xcode-frameworks/ProjectName_iosArm64.framework/ProjectName',
            '-arch', 'x86_64', 'ProjectName/build/xcode-frameworks/ProjectName_iosX64.framework/ProjectName',
            '-output', 'ProjectName/build/xcode-frameworks/ProjectName.framework/ProjectName',
    ]
}
combineIosArchitectures.dependsOn cleanFrameworksFolder
combineIosArchitectures.dependsOn runBuildIosArm64
combineIosArchitectures.dependsOn runBuildIosX64
```

Comment: Are you including multiple frameworks in iOS, or making one framework from multiple Kotlin libraries?

Comment: So far the frameworks have been included separately. Each of the Kotlin projects have the above Gradle script.

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2423

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev thanks, I had visited that thread before but wasn't in this phase then, it gave some helpful information. Will try some things out.